# PHP or HTML: Centering everything, but keeping them left-justified to each other

Tags: php, html

I have this php file:

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied."); ?>

<br/><br/>

<h1 class="error"><?php echo t('Page Not Found')?></h1>

<?php echo t('We searched but there is no page at this address.')?>

<?php  if (is_object($c)) { ?>
    <br/><br/>
    <?php  $a = new Area("Main"); $a->display($c); ?>
<?php  } ?>

<br/>

<img src="img.jpg">

<br/><br/>

<a href="<?php echo DIR_REL?>/"><?php echo t('Back to Home')?></a>.
```

and all the elements are aligned left. I want to modify this to keep all of the items left-justified with respect to each other, but center all of them together in the page.

For example, the above code:

```
Some text here.
Some big image here.
Some very very very long button here.
```

What I want is:

```
                        Some text here.
                        Some big image here.
                        Some very very very long button here.
```

I tried using two nested `div` tags as the following:

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied."); ?>

    <div align="center">
        <div align="left">

        <br/><br/>

        <h1 class="error"><?php echo t('Page Not Found')?></h1>

        <?php echo t('We searched but there is no page at this address.')?>

        <?php  if (is_object($c)) { ?>
            <br/><br/>
            <?php  $a = new Area("Main"); $a->display($c); ?>
        <?php  } ?>

        <br/>

        <img src="img.jpg">

        <br/><br/>

        <a href="<?php echo DIR_REL?>/"><?php echo t('Back to Home')?></a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

but this didn't work (didn't change anything--still left justified on the page). Any ideas? Is it even possible, or will I run into browser incompatibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dinamicaly wrap the divs
CSS:

```
.wrap img{
  max-width:100%;
  }
.container{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red;}
.wrap{
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container"><div class="wrap">
  <div>Hello World!</div>
  <div>Some bigger text</div>
  <div>Some more bigger text</div>
  <div><img src="image.jpg"/></div>
</div>
</div>
```

You could see it here in action:
http://cssdesk.com/KqFha

*Edited to add an image that fits the screen size

Comment: OK, this does what I asked. One question though. Is there anyway to set the width of the `wrap` section such that it auto-sizes with the browser window's width when the user changes it? I'd prefer the image to resize smaller instead of the browser's scrollbars appearing.

Comment: I dont't understand what is your question, because if the wrap fits the browser width, the content is not centered.

Comment: I've changed the container color to red in order you could see how the wrap fits the screen size if the row is bigger than the screen

Comment: The behavior i'm looking for is when the browser width is smaller than the content, the content width auto-sizes to the browser's width. This is the original file's behavior (I suppose it's built into my theme). As the browser width increases to become larger than the content's width, the content should center in the window (this is what I'm trying to introduce by modifying the code). Your code does seem to do this nicely with text. In my code, the image remains the same size, and the text doesn't wrap as in your example, when the browser window shrinks.

Comment: If I comment out the image line of code, I can reproduce your code's behavior. Perhaps you can add an image to your code and observe what I'm seeing. The image should resize smaller to fit 100% of the browser's width as the browser's width reduces smaller than the image's original width.

Comment: I've edited the code and inserted an image. With the max-width:100% you do the trick. I think it solves all your questions, if it does please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: You example works great. But, shouldn't there be two `</div>` at the end (is `<div>` a typo)?

Comment: Yes, those were two closing divs, sorry, i've corrected it

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div id="wrapper">  
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied."); ?>

<br/><br/>

<h1 class="error"><?php echo t('Page Not Found')?></h1>


<?php echo t('We searched but there is no page at this address.')?>

<?php  if (is_object($c)) { ?>
    <br/><br/>
    <?php  $a = new Area("Main"); $a->display($c); ?>
<?php  } ?>

<br/>

<img src="img.jpg">

<br/><br/>

<a href="<?php echo DIR_REL?>/"><?php echo t('Back to Home')?></a>.
</div><!--end wrapper-->
```

in your css

`#wrapper{width:800px;margin:0px auto;}`

Comment: Maybe a strange question but, is there a way to include the css inside the file (that is, just modify the file without requiring changes elsewhere)?

Comment: @ggkmath Sure, change id="wrapper" into style="width:800px;margin:0px auto;"

Comment: Great, now how to avoid hardcoding the width. The width should be whatever the browser window's width is (including when user resizes browser window)?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to center everything when using a width in percentage. When the window's width becomes larger than the content's width, the content is no longer centered in the window as the window is resized larger.

Comment: @ggkmath Sorry yes that would not work. Perhaps you really only want to apply a margin?  style="margin 0 80px;"

Comment: Wouldn't a margin only center everything at one particular width?

Comment: It would add a 80 margin on both sides of the content, so the content width will be browser width, minus 160px, centered